# How to dynamically update/resize the height of the JTextfield correctly so that it accommodates a runtime change of it's text font size?

Tags: swing, dynamic, fonts, jtextfield, autoresize

I need to know how to update/resize the height of the `JTextfield` correctly so that it accommodates a runtime change of it's text font size?

This code is an SSCCE of my situation. The code at first reads the font size from the `Preferences`; and returns a specified default (12) if no preference value has been saved yet. Then when you change the font size via the `JSpinner` it saves the new value in the `Preferences`, and it will read the saved value the next time you launch the app. The next time the app is launched; the `JtextField` will  be created with the new saved value of the font size. How to achieve the update/resize of the **height** dynamically?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.prefs.Preferences;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class Accommodated_JTextField extends JFrame implements ChangeListener {

    Preferences prefs;
    final String fontSizePref;

    JTextField textField;
    Font font;
    int fontSize;

    SpinnerNumberModel spinnerModel;
    JSpinner spinner_fontSize;

    public Accommodated_JTextField() {
        prefs = Preferences.systemNodeForPackage(Accommodated_JTextField.class);
        fontSizePref = "fontSizePref";

        fontSize = prefs.getInt(fontSizePref, 12);
        System.out.println(fontSize);
        font = new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.PLAIN, fontSize);

        textField = new JTextField(10);
        textField.setFont(font);

        spinnerModel = new SpinnerNumberModel(fontSize, 12, 40, 1);
        spinner_fontSize = new JSpinner(spinnerModel);
        spinner_fontSize.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(45, spinner_fontSize.getPreferredSize().height));
        spinner_fontSize.addChangeListener(this);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(textField);
        panel.add(spinner_fontSize);

        add(panel);

        setSize(700, 300);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        fontSize = ((Integer) spinner_fontSize.getValue());
        font = new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.PLAIN, fontSize);
        textField.setFont(font);
        prefs.putInt(fontSizePref, fontSize);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Accommodated_JTextField accommodated_textField = new Accommodated_JTextField();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to `revalidate` the container hierarchy and `repaint` the UI

Answer (score 2):

```
boolean packIt = false;

@Override
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
    fontSize = ((Integer) spinner_fontSize.getValue());
    font = new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.PLAIN, fontSize);
    textField.setFont(font);
    prefs.putInt(fontSizePref, fontSize);
    if (packIt) {
        pack(); // will resize the GUI to minimum size needed
        // this will result in a call to..
    } else {
        revalidate(); // tell the UI to revalidate itself
    }
}
```